# Input files with names which use MakeUppercase

Tags: macros, input

I have this simple document:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\inputFile}[2]
{%
    \input{"\MakeUppercase{#1} - \MakeUppercase{#2}"}%
}

\begin{document}
%
\inputFile{a}{b}
%
\end{document}
```

When I compile it, the error will be:

`! Illegal parameter number in definition of \@filef@und.`

My files contain spaces in their names (that's why I wrapped the file name in ""). I tried to do something with `\@@input`, but it didn't work well with files with spaces in their names. How could I deal with this please?

Comment: Make life easy for yourself: don't use weird characters in file names. If you must, you will need to assemble a suitable string and pass that to `\input`. You can't both protect the name using `"` and expect the expansion of certain bits inside the quotes to work.

Comment: If your macro did work, you'd be doing `\input{\input{"A - B"}}`. Surely you don't really have a file named `\input{"A = B"}`?

Comment: @cfr Assuming I don't have spaces in file names, how do I fix it anyway?

Comment: Well, either you enter expansion-land with Heiko as an expert guide, or you dodge the mental gymnastics and use `expl3`. Me, I find `expl3` provides sufficient mental workout, so I'd go with that. Your kilometres may vary, though. Heiko is an excellent guide, after all, whereas I'm the blind leading the sighted through a darkened catacomb with a stuttering candle. That is, I *like* the new `expl3` stuff. It's *logical*!

Comment: It isn't so much that you can't handle the spaces here. That's doable. It is that filenames like this are an endless source of headaches, complications and quantum entanglements. Since they are entirely avoidable, it just makes no sense to deal with them. Better save your energies for the headaches, complications and entanglements which really matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Converting to uppercase with `\MakeUppercase` or `\uppercase` is not compatible
with the expandable context needed for a file name for `\input`.
There are several workarounds:

If the simpler `\uppercase` can be used:

```
\uppercase{\input{"#1 - #2"}}
```

With `\MakeUppercase`:

```
\MakeUppercase{\protect\input{"#1 - #2"}}
```

Macro `\protect` prevents that `\input` is executed too early. `\MakeUppercase` expands the argument before converting to uppercase. Also, it puts the argument in a group. If this is not wanted, a global macro can be defined instead and later used as file name argument in `\input`.

```
\MakeUppercase{\gdef\noexpand\gtemp{"#1 - #2"}}\input{\gtemp}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `A - B.tex` contains

```
hylo
```

then

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Nn \patrik_inputfile:nn
{
  \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl  { \text_uppercase:n { #1 ~ - ~ #2 } }
  \file_input:V \l_tmpa_tl
}
\NewDocumentCommand \inputFile { m m }
{
  \group_begin:
  \patrik_inputfile:nn { #1 } { #2 }
  \group_end:
}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \file_input:n { V }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\inputFile{a}{b}
\end{document}
```

will generate a document saying 'hylo'.